# How can I remove a bathroom sink drain that has no visible nut?

Tags: bathroom, drain, sink

I am trying to remove my bathroom sink drain as it seems the o ring has broken.

I can't see any nut to unscrew. Can anyone help please?

Thanks.

[image: underside of drain]

Comment: look at the gray plastic nut on the horizontal bar ... now look at the metal downpipe ... see any similarity?

Answer (score 1):

I have never seen a drain assembly like the one you have but it probably unscrews from the top. If there is a name on the sink check with them to see if you need a special tool to remove part of the drain assembly from above.

Comment: That is a bit odd, but nothing _hugely_ unusual about it, I'd think. That's just the overflow drain in plastic running to an extra nipple at the bottom of the porcelain basin. Usually the overflow drain is cast right into the rest of the basin instead. I'd agree, though, that OP probably needs to unscrew from above.